# What is the difference between variable_ops_scope and variable_scope?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

In TensorFlow, there are two scope functions: `variable_ops_scope` and `variable_scope`. The first one has a signature as following:

```
variable_op_scope(values, name_or_scope, default_name,initializer, 
                  regularizer, caching_device, partitioner, reuse)
```

What does the first parameter `values` mean? `default_name` is only used when `name_or_scope` is `None`, so why this function need to take these two parameters? One parameter should be enough.

In general, what is the difference between these two scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variable_ops_scope` is a wrapper for `variable_scope`. Just like `tf.variable_scope`, but performs 2 more things:

1. Validate that values come from the same graph
2. If `name_or_scope` is `None`, the `default_name` will be used and will be uniquified if needed. Note that, if `name_or_scope` is not `None`, it will be used and but not be uniquified, and `default_name` will not be used.